# Stop Unity Inspector DecoratorDrawer chaining

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code looks like:

[image: C# Code]

The issue is that when adding DecoratorDrawer elements to the code they chain with all the following chained objects in the inspector so they look like this:

[image: Unity inspector with chained DecoratorDrawer elements]

Is there a way to keep the code as it is to make the inspector look like this, for example any kind of `[Space(10), showOnce=true]`:

[image: Optimal way the inspector in Unity should look]

or is there no way to stop the DecoratorDrawer from chaining with the built in inspector decorations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

---

#### Opinion

Then also in general personally I wouldn't use multiple inline declarations ever. This is way less maintainable / readable.

---

#### Issue

As you figured out multiple inline declarations means that attributes are applied to each individual field/property.

So basically your

```
[Header("Start points of the arrow")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_joystick, arrowpoint_trigger, arrowpoint_secondary;
```

equals writing

```
[Header("Start points of the arrow")][SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_joystick;
[Header("Start points of the arrow")][SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_trigger;
[Header("Start points of the arrow")][SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_secondary;
```

which is of course not what you want to do.

#### Solution

Instead of

```
[Header("Start points of the arrow")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_joystick, arrowpoint_trigger, arrowpoint_secondary;

[Space(10)]
[Header("List of secondary bezier points")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_joystickBezierPoint, arrowpoint_triggerBezierPoint, arrowpoint_secondaryBezierPoint;
```

I would rather make it

```
[Header("Start points of the arrow")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_joystick;
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_trigger;
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_secondary;

[Space(10)]

[Header("List of secondary bezier points")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_joystickBezierPoint;
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_triggerBezierPoint
[SerializeField] private GameObject arrowpoint_secondaryBezierPoint;
```

and (both) "issue" (and opinion) are already resolved and also this way in code it looks more similar to how it will look like in the Inspector. And that without the need for external libraries. (Odin sometimes brings other issues due to its "magic" serializations ;) )

Comment: Indeed, I mean that's how I wrote the code to get the "optimal inspector" image, though I personally prefer declaring all variables in one line - but I am now the wiser and will just have to choose ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare multiple variables in a row, they receive all the attributes.

Writing [Space(10)] will not add space at this point in the inspector, but will decorate the field with an attribute that the serializer picks up, resulting in a different layout. However, this attribute will be assigned to all of the fields, resulting in the layout you get. So no, I don't think you can do it this way.

The [Odin Inspector](https://odininspector.com/) has grouping features like this, but the ones from Unity will still behave like in your problem.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just like to declare multiple variables on the same row for clean code

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: This would not happen to me, because I do not think of this as clean code. But now we are talking preferences and you wanted a solution to your problem and unfortunately I do not think there is one.

Comment: No exactly, I've searched around but couldn't find if this was possible or not